# Install Snow Leopard 10.6.3 on 2010 Mac Pro

Tags: install, snow-leopard, mac-pro

I am trying to install Snow Leopard 10.6.3 on a 2010 Mac Pro Quad Core Intel but on a secondary drive that is a solid state drive. My Mac Pro is only upgradable to El Capitan which I am running now on original hard drive. There are currently some glitches with installed system software on original drive and it's very slow to start up.

I spoke with Apple and they stated to start with Snow Leopard CD and upgrade to El Capitan online,

When I put Snow Leopard in I get a white circle with X thru install. Error comes up:
You can't use this version of the application "Install Mac OS X" with thie version of OX. You have to "Install Mac OS X" 23.1.1

I'm tried rebooting from install disk, but it wouldn't boot. My MacBook Laptop does not have a CD drive so I can't do it by connecting that one. Urg!

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Liz

Comment: A 2010 Mac Pro Quad Core requires OS X 10.6.4. OS X 10.6.3 should not work. Your should be able to install a version newer than El Capitan. What is OS X 23.1.1? Have you tried creating an El Captain USB installer? How about [High Sierra](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208969)?

Comment: Just download **OS X El Capitan** from **Apple** and create a **USB Installer** and then boot your **Mac Pro** with it and install **OS X El Capitan** on the second drive.

Comment: Apple Tech support instructed that I needed to install Snow Leopard first, then upgrade to El Capitan.

Comment: 10.6.4 was not released til Mid June. I purchased my Mac end of May

Comment: RE: "Apple Tech support instructed that I needed to install Snow Leopard first, then upgrade to El Capitan." -- If you are going to listen to **Apple Tech Support** then why did you post a question here!? What I said is absolutely doable and there is no need to first install **MacOS X Snow Leopard** to then upgrade it! Creating a **USB Installer** of **OS X El Capitan** bypasses that needless step. That is, if you will listen to someone that just happens to know more than **Apple Tech Support** in this particular instance!

Comment: Assuming you have **OS X El Capitan** under **Purchased** in the **App Store** you should be able to download it again and when it's finished downloading, force quit the installer in order to keep it from self-deleting (_right-click_ and press _option_ and select **Force Quit** on its **Dock Tile**), and then create a **USB Installer** from the **Install OS X El Capitan.app** _bundle_ on an **8 GB USB 2** _flash drive_. See: [How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/HT201372). Then boot your **Mac** with it and install it to the _target drive_.

Comment: BTW If you do not have **OS X El Capitan** under **Purchased** in the **App Store** you can download from the link in step 4 in [How to upgrade to OS X El Capitan](https://support.apple.com/HT206886), and the direct download link is: [Download OS X El Capitan](http://updates-http.cdn-apple.com/2019/cert/061-41424-20191024-218af9ec-cf50-4516-9011-228c78eda3d2/InstallMacOSX.dmg)

Comment: Thanks for the info...I'll give it a whirl!